# Group by Month and Year Format in Query as 2017-07

Tags: sql-server, datetime, group-by

Here's my query:

```
select convert(date, create_timestamp) as date
,sum(count(*)) over (order by convert(date, create_timestamp)) as cumulative
from job_posting jp
group by convert(date, create_timestamp)
order by convert(date, create_timestamp)
```

It groups by date and shows the following results:

```
2015-09-02   1
2015-09-03   2
2015-09-04   5
2015-09-05   7
2015-09-07   14
```

I'd like to make a new query to return the results grouped by month and year to look like this:

```
2015-09
2015-10
2015-11
```

I'm struggling to find the right SQL command to help with this.  This line is causing issues:

```
,sum(count(*)) over (order by convert(date, create_timestamp)) as cumulative
```

Comment: select CONVERT (varchar(10), create_timestamp, 103) AS [DD/MM/YYYY] for full format, now you can use it as per the needs you wanted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice the converting to `varchar(7)`

**Example**

```
Select convert(varchar(7),create_timestamp,23)
```

**Returns**

```
2017-09
```

Comment: FYI the ,23 is optional.  I just think it is a good practice to define it.